# Was ist „Liedern“ im Goethes Ginkgo Biloba Gedicht?

Tags: poetry

Das Ende

> Fühlst du nicht an meinen Liedern,
>    Daß ich Eins und doppelt bin?

des folgenden [Gedichtes](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1518/1691) kann ich leider nicht verstehen.

```
Dieses Baums Blatt, der von Osten
Meinem Garten anvertraut,
Giebt geheimen Sinn zu kosten,
Wie’s den Wissenden erbaut,

Ist es Ein lebendig Wesen,
Das sich in sich selbst getrennt?
Sind es zwei, die sich erlesen,
Daß man sie als Eines kennt?

Solche Frage zu erwidern,
Fand ich wohl den rechten Sinn,
Fühlst du nicht an meinen Liedern,
Daß ich Eins und doppelt bin?  

Goethe
```

Einige meinen, dass das Ich Goethe selbst sei (und nicht irgendwelches Ich). Dementstprechend wären die *Lieder* eine Darstellung seines Werkes, könnte ich vermuten. Was soll dann das Doppelte dabei sein?

Soll diese Interpretation auch Quatsch sein, was sind die Lieder?

Comment: Goethe... ein vielfach überschätzter Schriftsteller.

Comment: ...was jedoch die Frage nicht unberechtigt macht. Wer auch immer das geschrieben hat, ist die Sprache richtig, und ich muß verstehen können. (Wenn das ironisch gemeint war, wüsste ich nicht wieso.)

Comment: Die Frage sollte durch die drei Antworten geklärt sein (vor allem durch Christian Geiselmanns Antwort). Die Wahl des Wortes "Liedern" (statt "Gedichten" o.ä.) dürfte darauf beruhen, dass ein Reim zu "erwidern" gesucht war. Obwohl Goethe sicher auch zu "Gedichten" einen Reim hätte finden können  ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Du bist aller Wahrscheinlichkeit nach auf der richtigen Fährte.

> Fühlst du nicht an meinen Liedern

bezieht sich auf seine Werke.

> Daß ich Eins und doppelt bin?

bezieht sich darauf, dass es quasi zwei Goethe gibt. Die Privatperson/Menschen und den Dichter. Also eine Person die durch die Gedichte, Lieder, etc erscheint und eine die als normaler Mensch anders erscheint, aber trotzdem sind sie eins. (Irgendwie muss ich gerade an Batman und Bruce Wayne denken ;) )

> »… daß ich Eins und doppelt bin«. Für Goethe symbolisierte das gefächerte Ginkgo-Blatt seine gespaltene Existenz als Mensch und Dichter.

**EDIT**

Ich beziehe mich hier mal auf den Wikipedia-Artikel [Marianne von Willemer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marianne_von_Willemer) und werde nicht tiefer in die Biographien der Personen eintauchen.

Die Einladung des Ehemannes an den Ort des Geschehens lautete:

> Erholen sie sich doch bald von den Beschwerden des Winters zu Weimar an den Ufern des Mains. Sie könnten ja die Vor-Kur zu Oberrad einleiten und bei uns auf der Mühle wohnen. Platz ist genug da, und meine Frau und ich würden nie eine größere Freude empfunden haben wie die, Sie als Gastfreund bei uns zu sehen. Wenn Sie der Sonne müd sind, und der Arbeit, singt sie Ihnen von Ihren Liedern vor.

Zitat Wikipedia

> Mittags speiste man gemeinsam und flanierte am Nachmittag in der ländlichen Umgebung. Goethe trug am Abend seine am Tag entstanden Verse vor, und Marianne sang nicht nur seine Lieder, sondern trat mit ihm zunehmend in einen lyrischen Dialog.

Wenn das Gedicht als solches an sie adressiert war kann man behaupten, dass mit Lieder seine Werke im allgemeinen oder zumindest diese Lieder im speziellen gemeint sind, von denen er wusste, dass sie ihr bekannt waren und über die er sicherlich auch mit ihr gesprochen hat.

Da sie sich dabei auch persönlich kennengelernt haben (ich spreche nicht von Liebesbeziehung o.ä. sondern einfach nur von persönlichem kennenlernen) kann er hier wie gesagt auf die Ambivalenz zwischen privater und dichterischer (öffentlich wahrgenommener) Person verweisen. Die Eins sind, aber eben auch geteilt. Man sollte dabei auch beachten, dass vielfach davon ausgegangen wird, dass Strophe 1+3 erst später an anderer Stelle entstanden und ihr der bekannte Gesamtbrief später über einen Umweg zugesandt wurde.

[Quelle: Siegfried Unseld, Goethe und der Ginkgo - Ein Baum und ein Gedicht](https://www.suhrkamp.de/buecher/goethe_und_der_ginkgo-siegfried_unseld_35752.html)

Comment: Das *Du* ist bloß der Leser und nicht eine Person, der das Gedicht gewidmet war?

Comment: @c.p. Ich denke nicht, dass das eine Auswirkung auf die Aussage hat. Höchstens auf die Beziehung des lyrischen Ichs zum "lyrischen Du". Betrachtet man allerdings die Entstehungsgeschichte (1. + 3. Strophe entstanden etwa wahrscheinlich erst leicht später) hatte er wohl zunächst die Empfängerin des Briefs im Sinn. vgl [hier](https://www.grin.com/document/59520) und [hier](https://lektuerehilfe.de/johann-wolfgang-von-goethe/gedichte/analyse-und-interpretation/gingo-biloba). Mit der allgemeinen Veröffentlichung hat sich das evtl verschoben.

Answer (score 3):

Dieses Gedicht hat Johann Wolfgang von Goethe am 15. September 1815 für seine späte Liebe Marianne von Willemer geschrieben, die er im Jahr 1814 als eine verheiratete Frau kennengelernt hat und legte als Ausdruck seiner Zuneigung zwei Ginkgo-Blätter bei.

Nach der letzten Begegnung im September 1815 in Heidelberg hat Goethe ein Wiedersehen mit der geliebten Marianne vermieden.

> Fühlst du nicht an meinen Liedern

Hier verweist er auf sein Werk (seine Lieder).

> Daß ich Eins und doppelt bin?

Das im Originalgedicht beigefügte Ginkgoblatt wird zum Sinnbild (Einheit und Zweiheit) für die zu diesem Zeitpunkt tiefe Liebe und stellt gleichzeitig die  Zerissenheit der Liebe (damals wahrscheinlich aus gesellschaftlichen Zwängen begründet) und des Empfindens für die 35 Jahre jüngere Marianne dar. Später entwickelt sich  zwischen Goethe und Marianne von Willemer ein langjähriger und freundschaftlicher Briefwechsel.

[image]

Quelle Wikipedia: [Gingo biloba](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gingo_biloba)

Comment: Die Frage war aber nach Bedeutung von *Liedern*, nicht nach Bedeutung von *Ginkgoblatt*.

Comment: D.h., die Antwort soll ausdrücken, dass Goethe für von Willemer sowohl Liebe/haber als auch Freund/schaft sein möchte? (Falls ja, steht mir das zu indirekt in der Antwort)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm  Ich hätte jetzt, wenn schon, dann doch eher hineingelesen, dass der Dichter sich, wiewohl räumlich getrennt, ganz ganz doll eins fühlt mit der Angebeteten. Ist ja kein untypisches Gefühl für Verliebte. Allerdings dadurch auch eine eher platte Beobachtung. Aber gut, wenn's nur in der Liebeskommunikation steht, kann man ihm's nicht wirklich vorwerfen. Wir schreiben alle solches Zeug, wenn wir verliebt sind.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn wir davon ausgehen, dass Goethe diese Verse an eine Geliebte geschickt hat (wie help-info-de in seiner Antwort zu berichten wusste), dann meint *Lieder* hier kaum sein gesamtes Werk, sondern ganz einfach die Gedichte, die er ihr in früheren Briefen schon geschickt hatte.

Die Verwendung von "Lieder" für "Gedichte" ist ja in der älteren Literatur sehr häufig. Einfacher Grund: "Gedichte" passt oft ganz schlecht in einen Vers. "Lieder" lässt sich in rhythmischen Texten meist viel leichter verarbeiten. Auch tönt "Lieder" mit dem langen "i" poetischer und liebeslyrischer als das enge, tonlose, kurzvokalige "Gedicht", das bei sorgloser Aussprache unschön klingen kann wie das Zischen einer Espressomaschine.

Seltenes Gegenbeispiel: G.s Zeilen in einem ähnlichem Kontext:

> Dein Schweigen währt schon sieben Tage.
>   Ein dumpfes Ahnen mich beschleicht.
>   Erlaube mir die plumpe Frage:
>   Hat mein Gedicht dich nicht erreicht?

Hier arbeitet G. mit den Zischlauten von "Gedicht", die im "dich nicht" und "erreicht" wiederholt und unterstrichen werden, und spielt onomatopoetisch damit auf das Seufzen des vernachlässigten Liebhabers an.